# Does hosting an appengine app on custom domain force me to be a google apps customer?

Tags: google-app-engine

- I have a domain I bought (via godaddy.com) - let's call it xyz.com
- I have an gae app - let's call it xyzweb.appspot.com
- I added a masked redirect at godaddy dns management console and now xyz.com gets    redirected to xyzweb.appspot.com (even though the address bar shows xyz.com)

This stops working well in some cases like when I give a direct url redirect like  href='/static/url/tohelppage.html' or when I attempt to redirect for OAuth authorization.  So I read other posts on what I need to do and the most referred one was https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/domain.

Based on that page it appears that it is necessary to sign up for a new Google Apps account with the new domain name?

- So I Have to pay for Google Apps separately beyond what I am paying for Google AppEngine?
- And also manage a separate apps domain and its services?  I already have google apps domains and this seems more overhead to run a small app on gae.

Could you please help me understand if I've understood this right?  And if there is a way to avoid the additional overhead of an extra google apps account?

Comment: are you sure you have to pay for linking the new domain name with the existing appspot domain ?

Comment: I probably won't have to pay if I use the standard option - <http://www.google.com/enterprise/apps/business/pricing.html>.  But it still is one more thing to manage and it seems like running a separate or a sub company.

What do other companies do?  If, say, SONY is starting a new product website with a new domain name, they have to set up a new business app account just for one small product?  It doesn't sound sensible to me.

Comment: oh come on, you are enjoying those free applications right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that I do this, is I set up a basic google apps account (which is free), and I link the GAE app to my google apps account. Then you can set google apps to alias "www" to the appengine app, and now your appengine app works on www.yourdomain.tld

It's explained more [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/domain), which I know you already looked at, but it explains it well. Try reading it again.

Comment: That's where I'm wondering about the overhead.  I already have a business apps account under a parent company name.  But this is one of its products though it is disassociated from the parent name.  Now I will need to create this like a subsidiary company (at least logically) with google apps and manage that domain also with separate email ids, passwords, service management, et al?

Comment: You don't need to change everything over to google apps, (its going to want you to, but you have the power). And google apps doesn't care that it's a company. Just sign up [here](http://www.google.com/enterprise/apps/business/pricing.html), and only set up the domain alias for appengine.

Comment: I finally did that. All ok. But I still have that extra overhead to manage. :-)